# "can I speak to Mr Tom" or "May I speak to Mr Tom" which one is correct

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, modal-verbs, can-may

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can/May/Will you help me with this?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4919/can-may-will-you-help-me-with-this)
>   [Difference between “can” and “may”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54340/difference-between-can-and-may)

> - Can I speak to Mr Tom?
> - May I speak to Mr Tom?

Which one is correct?

My thinking is that *can* expresses the ability to do something while *may* expresses permission.

Here I am  asking for permission so I want to use *may*, but some people use *can* as well. So which one is correct?

Comment: See: [Difference between “can” and “may”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54340/difference-between-can-and-may) and a number of other [similar questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=can+may).