# What's the difference between may and can in the context?

Tags: grammar

I would be grateful if someone would explain the difference between "swimming can/may be dangerous".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "can" and "may"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54340/difference-between-can-and-may). In the case of something like your "warning" message, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, **can** refers to something being physically possible, while **may** implies permission or possibility. **May** is also softer and more polite.

For example: You **can** get sick by riding roller coasters. It is physically possible for you to get sick by doing that.

For example: "**May** I use the restroom?" Johnny asked the teacher. Yes, Johnny could have used **can** but if he did, the teacher could say, "I don't know if you can or not, Johnny. Would you like to demonstrate?" :)