# May and Can: Which one should I pick

Tags: grammar

I want to know if I should use `may` or  `can` for this sentence:

```
**Can** I borrow your book
**May** I borrow your book
```

I want to know which is more suitable in the context of politeness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "can" and "may"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54340/difference-between-can-and-may)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***May*** is more polite.

***Can*** is - colloquial, for lack of a better word, and far more popular among the masses. Should be said with a smile, though, to compensate.

Comment: It sort of help but I would also like answers with more examples

Comment: In my early schooldays, if we said to a teacher "Can I go to the toilet?" the response was usually "You can, but you may not". The question had to be correctly asked to get permission.

Comment: @Darkrai - this question has been closed because it has already been asked and answered.